# VS2010 and OpenCV: Stack around a variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

The code below is giving me the following error when running in Visual Studio 2010: `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'keypoints' was corrupted.`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat image = imread("C:/IMAGE.JPG");

    SiftFeatureDetector detector;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

    detector.detect(image, keypoints);

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to compile `OpenCV` library using Visual Studio 2010 rather than just linking to precompiled `dll`s and such. All is well now.

Comment: How did you figure it out ? You can always use pre- compiled  libraries given from OpenCV

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
Mat image = imread("C:/IMAGE.JPG");
```

might be failing. You need to make sure `image` was successfully loaded before passing it as a parameter to other functions:

```
if (!image.data )
{
    cout <<  "Could not load image" << endl ;
    return -1;
}
```

If `imread()` is failing and the file exist in that location, you might want to use the other slash, and escape it:

```
Mat image = imread("C:\\IMAGE.JPG");
```

If the image is being loaded successfully and the crash remains, try to load the image as grayscale:

```
Mat image = imread("C:\\IMAGE.JPG", 0);
```

Comment: Also, make sure you have the permission to read `C:/IMAGE.JPG`.

Comment: `imread` completes with success (i have replaced `/` with `\\`) but i still have the problem. i debugged the program and the stack corruption error occurs right at the end of the program... seem like it is happening when `keypoints` vector is being cleaned up.